# How to get a meta tag content value and do a substraction

Tags: javascript, html

I want to grab the meta tag content value and then do a substraction.

Can anyone help me please?

The meta tag looks like this:

```html
<meta itemprop="price" content="1699">
```

I tried this but it does not work:

```js
var oldprice = document.body.querySelector("[itemprop~=price][content]").content;

var newprice = oldprice - 500;
```

Comment: That's because you refer to body when meta tags are in head.... try to omit `.body` and refer directly to document like `document.querySelector(ecc...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Gicu Aftene comment. Meta tags are in head of document.
Doing `document.head.` didn't work with querySelector even though `document.head` does return head.

```js
// document.head... doesn't work
let oldprice = document.querySelector('meta[itemprop="price"]').content;
let newprice = oldprice - 500;

console.log(newprice)
```

```html
<meta itemprop="price" content="1699">
```